# C++11 lock free stack

Tags: c++11, stack, lock-free

I'm reading *C++ Concurrency in Action* by Anthony Williams, and don't understand its `push` implementation of the `lock_free_stack` class.

Why on earth the atomic `load` is not in the while loop ? The reason he gave is:

> You therefore don’t have to reload head each time through the loop,
>   because the compiler does that for you.

But I don't get the picture. Can someone shed some light on this?

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
private:
 struct node
 {
   T data;
   node* next;
   node(T const& data_) : 
     data(data_)
   {}
 };
 std::atomic<node*> head;
public:
 void push(T const& data)
 {
   node* const new_node=new node(data); 
   new_node->next=head.load(); 
   while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next,new_node)); 
 }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is in the interface to [`compare_exchange_weak`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange), which in this case takes 2 arguments.  The first is a reference to the expected value, and the second is the desired. If the current value of the atomic is not equal to the expected input, it will return false and the expected input is set to the current value.

So in this case,  what it's doing is setting `new_node->next = head`.  Then, it's saying if `head` is still equal to `new_node->next`, swap it into `head`.  If it's no longer that value, it uses the reference to `new_node->next` to assign it the current value of `head`.  Since every iteration of the loop that fails also replaces `new_node->next` with the current value of `head`, there is no read to duplicate that in the body of the loop.

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of `compare_exchange_weak`:

> Atomically compares the value stored in *this with the value of
>   expected, and if those are equal, replaces the former with desired
>   (performs read-modify-write operation). Otherwise, loads the actual
>   value stored in *this into expected (performs load operation).

As you see, *otherwise* the actual value of `head` is loaded into expected.